Проблемы с наследованием ООП
пишу калькулятор, калькулятор состоит из двух режимов, обычного и расширенного, в обычном режиме(наследуется от родительского) вызываю опрелеленный метод родительского класса получается все как надо, переключаюсь в расширенный режим, там так же этот метод вызывается, хотя я его явно не вызываю. Может, кто нибудь здесь ответит на этот вопрос?
from tkinter import *
tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class Calculator(Tk):
# Создание класса для перехода между режимами калькулятора, логика калькулятора, и виджеты калькулятора
# переход между режимами калькулятора
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       box_container = Frame(self)
       box_container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
       box_container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
       box_container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    self.modes = {}
    for K, geometry, title, in zip((RegularCalculatorMode, AdvancedCalculatorMode),
                                   ('274x380+500+100', '630x620+380+10'), ("Калькулятор обычный режим ",
                                                                           "Калькулятор расширенный режим")):
        pages = K.__name__
        box = K(parent=box_container, controller=self)
        self.modes[pages] = (box, geometry, title)
        box.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    self.show_frame("RegularCalculatorMode")

    def show_frame(self, RegularCalculatorMode):
        box, geometry, title = self.modes[RegularCalculatorMode]
        self.update_idletasks()
        self.geometry(geometry)
        self.title(title)
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        box.tkraise()

   #создание дисплея для обычного калькулятора
    def entry_display(self):
        self.entry_display = Entry(width=22,highlightthickness=4,highlightbackground='black',font=('Arial', 15,'bold'),justify='right')
        self.entry_display.insert('0','0')
        self.entry_display.place(x=10,y=20)

    #создание дисплея для расширенного калькулятора
    def text_display(self, height, x, y, width, chars=0):
        self.text_display = ScrolledText(self, font=('Arial', 20, 'bold'), width=width, height=height,
                                     highlightthickness=4, highlightbackground='black')
        self.text_display.tag_configure('tag-right', justify='right')
        self.text_display.insert('end', chars, 'tag-right')
        self.text_display.place(x=x, y=y)

    # создание кнопки меню, переход между режимами калькулятора
    def buttom_menu(self, x, y, command):
        button_menu = Button(self, bg='red', text='≡', width=4, font=('Arial', 10,'bold'), bd=5, fg='black',
                         command=command)
        button_menu.place(x=x, y=y)

class RegularCalculatorMode(Frame, Calculator):
# создание класса обычного режима калькулятора
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.entry_display()
        self.buttom_menu(10, 90, lambda: controller.show_frame("AdvancedCalculatorMode"))


class AdvancedCalculatorMode(Frame, Calculator):
# создание класса расширенного режима калькулятора
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.text_display(4, 10, 10, 16, 0)
        self.buttom_menu(10, 170, lambda: controller.show_frame("RegularCalculatorMode"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    calk = Calculator()
    calk.mainloop()
    


О каком методе речь? И скорее всего вы неправильно активизируете фрейм, дело вообще не в ООП, а в правильной методике работе с tkinter. Я не разбираюсь в tkinter, в чём именно дело не подскажу.

о методе self.entry_display(), не понимаю почему он вызывается, когда переходишь в расширенный режим, ведь в классе class AdvancedCalculatorMode, он невызывается

Дочерние фреймы не должны наследоваться от вашего класса приложения. Уберите наследование от Calculator.

не чего не меняется, проблема остается

все разобрался надо было при создании entry, прописать родительское окно

@ДмитрийМиронов Тогда можете сами оформить ответ на свой вопрос. Только не повторяйте весь одинаковый код, старайтесь по минимуму код копировать - покажите только то, что поменяли и немного контекста вокруг.

Надо было при создании entry прописать родительское окно.
Было:
def entry_display(self):
     self.entry_display = Entry(width=22,highlightthickness=4,highlightbackground='black',font=('Arial', 15,'bold'),justify='right')
     self.entry_display.insert('0','0')
     self.entry_display.place(x=10,y=20)

Исправил на:
def entry_display(self):
    self.entry_display = Entry(self,width=22,highlightthickness=4,highlightbackground='black',font=('Arial', 15,'bold'),justify='right')
    self.entry_display.insert('0','0')
    self.entry_display.place(x=10,y=20)

